# SignalR - How to access user mapping in other server side class to send notifications to a particular user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I have implemented In-memory storage mapping in my MVC project to store the userId and its related connectionsId as shown in the mapping link below. The problem is that I am not able to access the mapping instance in the other server side class and send notification to a particular user. How should I modify Hub or SendNotification class to send Notification. Please let me know how to do it.

```
\\ here is the sample hub class with onconnected and disconnted same as in mapping link
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections =  new ConnectionMapping<string>();

    public void SendChatMessage(string who, string message)
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(who))
        {
            Clients.Client(connectionId).addChatMessage(name + ": " + message);
        }
    }
}

\\ other server class where to call hub
public class SendNotification
{
    Public void SaveToDb(string userName, class entity)
    {
        // save to database call
        // send Notification to User userName through SignalR if user Exists in Mapping
    }
}
```

Here's a SignalR Mapping link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)!

Here's How to access hub outside (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Backplane documentation?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr.

We have a multi-instance web tier with many SignalR clients.  Any instance in the web tier can talk to any browser client.  The code in the Hub does not change.  There is just additional logic at startup-- see the above documentation.